# Unable to catch response from rest API

Tags: angular, rest, api, linkedin-api

I am trying to call the linkedIn access token API within angular 2 application.
I am able to see response in chrome debugging Network. API is returning data perfectly but my problem is in my app i am not able to catch that response. 
Following is my code.

```
 getProfileData() {

    //IN.API.Raw("https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~?oauth2_access_token=" + this.code + "&format=json").result(this.displayProfiles).error(this.displayProfilesErrors);
    this.apiclass.GetTokenAPILink(this.code).subscribe(
        x => {
            this.datalink = x;
            console.log("Linkedin",x)
        });

}
  public GetTokenAPILink(code: any): Observable<any> {
    return this.LinkedinAPIWithHttpInfo(code)
        .map((response: Response) => {
            if (response.status === 204) {
                return undefined;
            } else {
                return response.json() || {};
            }
        });
}
public LinkedinAPIWithHttpInfo(code:any): Observable<Response> {
    const path = "https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken?grant_type=authorization_code&code=" + code + "&redirect_uri=http://localhost:4200/ProfileLogin&client_id=--clientID--&client_secret=--key--";

    let queryParameters = new URLSearchParams();
    let headers = new Headers(this.defaultHeaders.toJSON()); // https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6845


    // to determine the Content-Type header
    let consumes: string[] = [
        'application/json',
        'text/json',
        'application/xml',
        'text/xml',
        'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    ];

    // to determine the Accept header
    let produces: string[] = [
    ];

    headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

    let requestOptions: RequestOptionsArgs = new RequestOptions({
        method: RequestMethod.Post,
        headers: headers,
        body: "Hi"
    });
    // https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues/4037


    return this.http.request(path, requestOptions);
}
```

This following part not catching response from API

```
return this.LinkedinAPIWithHttpInfo(code)
        .map((response: Response) => {
            if (response.status === 204) {
                return undefined;
            } else {
                return response.json() || {};
            }
        });
```

Comment: if you put a console.log statement inside `if (response.status === 204)` block does it log in dev tools ?

Comment: control is not even going inside that block.

Comment: use if (response.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)  once may it will will help you.

Comment: What is the status of request that you see in dev console?

Comment: @Timothy it's 200 OK

Answer (score 0):

I think your request is returning some  codes which qualify for error (i.e. less than 200 and greater than 299) and so error callback is being invoked. May be a permanent redirection etc, not sure.

Put an error callback in your subscribe and check what is the error

getProfileData() {

```
//IN.API.Raw("https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~?oauth2_access_token=" + this.code + "&format=json").result(this.displayProfiles).error(this.displayProfilesErrors);
this.apiclass.GetTokenAPILink(this.code).subscribe(
    x => {
        this.datalink = x;
        console.log("Linkedin",x)
    }, error => {
   console.log("Error is ",error);

  });
```

This will print the error that you are getting ,and should be able to guide you in right direction.

Comment: it's error. false
status
:
0
statusText
:
""
type
:
3

Comment: In else block of map simply return Json without any pipe...
return response.json()